# Stop gif on mover hover does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, jpeg, gif

I want to show a GIF first and when the mouse hovers on the GIF it should show a different JPG picture – so that it looks like it stopped.

I tried this code but it didn't work. 
I would like to know which part needs to be fixed.

```
<html>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#imgDino").hover(
        function()
        {
            $(this).attr("src",
            "http://s2.favim.com/610/150619/airplane-fly-landscape-plane-Favim.com-2831842.jpg");
        },
        function()
        {
            $(this).attr("src", "https://66.media.tumblr.com/233306b207ff895cc591ee86684fd792/tumblr_mze5yi7uwQ1sqqsygo1_400.gif");
        }                         
    );                  
});
</script>
 <body>
    <img id="imgDino" src="https://66.media.tumblr.com/233306b207ff895cc591ee86684fd792/tumblr_mze5yi7uwQ1sqqsygo1_400.gif" />

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here with your code:

1. You are not loading jQuery - so you can't use it. And the console (F12) throws an error for that: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`
2. You are registering the javascript-event before the dom-element is available

So a working solution for your scenario would be:

```html
<html>

  <head>

  </head>

  <body>
    <img id="imgDino" src="https://66.media.tumblr.com/233306b207ff895cc591ee86684fd792/tumblr_mze5yi7uwQ1sqqsygo1_400.gif" />

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#imgDino").hover(
          function() {
            $(this).attr("src",
              "http://s2.favim.com/610/150619/airplane-fly-landscape-plane-Favim.com-2831842.jpg");
          },
          function() {
            $(this).attr("src", "https://66.media.tumblr.com/233306b207ff895cc591ee86684fd792/tumblr_mze5yi7uwQ1sqqsygo1_400.gif");
          }
        );
      });

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You script is using syntax from JQuery, add the following between your `<head></head>` tags:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

The code will work as expected after you do this (though the effect looks kinda weird with the images used by the script).

Also, as this question is related to JQuery, you should add that tag to your question.